# AngularJS filter in tree with n depth

Tags: angularjs, filter, tree

I wanted to do the same of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926823/angularjs-filter-with-multiple-perms)
for an array with *n* depth. I have the same json with id, name and parent_id (not type). I've tried with ng-template but it does not work for me.

How could i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I acknowledge you weren't able to use the tree solution provided in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926823/angularjs-filter-with-multiple-perms)
so here is a fiddle of tree of users using angularjs

```
<ul>
    <!--only get top level nodes where parent_id=0 though filtering -->
    <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{parent_id:0}:true" ng-include="'userTree'"></li>
</ul>
<!--inside template filter to only get children of this user-->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="userTree">
    {{user.name}}

    <ul ng-if="has_children(user)" style="margin-left:10px">

        <li ng-repeat="child in users | filter:{parent_id:user.id}:true " ng-include="'userTree'" ng-init="user=child">
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.has_children = function(user) {
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
        if (user.id == $scope.users[i].parent_id) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

This is the link for working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ymb9konk/

Comment: That's it. I think my problem was that i always forgot ng-init.